# How to change the timestamp DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) to return 23:59:59.000 instead of 00:00:00.000

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, datetime

```
Select DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
```

returns

```
2020-08-31 00:00:00.000
```

How do i modify it to return

```
2020-08-31 23:59:59.000
```

I tried replacing the -1 and 0 but it doesnt help.

Comment: Simply replacing the keyword `DAY` by `SECOND` as: `Select DATEADD(SECOND, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the last second of last month, you can do:

```
select dateadd(
    day,
    -1,
    datetimefromparts(
        year(getdate()),
        month(getdate()),
        1,
        23,
        59,
        59,
        0
    )
)
```

Or:

```
select dateadd(
    second,
    -1,
    cast(datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1) as datetime)
)
```

I wonder why you want to generate such value. If that's about generating an inclusive upper bound to filter (as with `between` operator), then it is simpler to use an excluding upper bound, like:

```
where date_col <  '2020-08-31'
```

Instead of:

```
where date_col <= '2020-08-31 23:59:59.000'
```

Comment: Thank you, Exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Why not subtract a single second from the offset of 0?

```
select DateAdd(Second, -1, DateAdd(Day, 0, DateAdd(Month, DateDiff(Month, 0, SysDateTime()), 0)))
```

Returns:

```
YYYY-MM-DDT23:59:59Z
```

Where DD represents "The end of the month."